# What are the various combinations of Rudraksha and their affects on humans?

Tags: rudraksha

I've heard that using a couple of 6 faced with a 5 faced rudraksha emhances the concentration power. Where can I know other combinations and their impact.

Comment: There are uses of ekamukhi to chaturdashamukhi rudrakshas.They give different results.But there are rule of wearing both  navamukha and chaturdasa-mukha simultaneously.But scriptures so far as i know do not give the results of combinations.What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I referred to this link. http://www.rudrakshapowers.com/rudraksh-combination.html

Comment: These all seem their construction without scriptural basis.

Comment: It is the only reason to come up with this question. I need an answer that says the combination benefits (if there are any). And thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are welcome.The benefits mentioned in the shastras are all spiritual and have nothing to do with blood circulation etc.